# Error instantiating snitch class 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, terraform, cassandra-2.2

I'm having hard time setting up 2 node Cassandra  cluster on Ec2 instances. This is 2.2.19 version. I cannot upgrade due to some other dependencies involved.

The Ec2 instances are in private subnet. Assigned static private ips

Here is my cassandra.yaml

```
cluster_name: 'Test-cluster'
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000

commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32

seed_provider:
    # Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points.
    # Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
    # the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
    # multiple nodes!
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "${private_ip}"
listen_address: ${private_ip}
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
storage_port: 7000
num_tokens: 32
ssl_storage_port: 9042
start_rpc: true
rpc_address: ${private_ip}
rpc_port: 9160
broadcast_rpc_address: ${private_ip}
endpoint_snitch: Ec2Snitch
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner
```

Here is my system.log

```
INFO  [main] 2021-06-07 18:42:41,900 DatabaseDescriptor.java:327 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2021-06-07 18:42:42,022 DatabaseDescriptor.java:437 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 251MB
INFO  [main] 2021-06-07 18:42:42,023 DatabaseDescriptor.java:441 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 251MB
ERROR [main] 2021-06-07 18:42:42,049 CassandraDaemon.java:787 - Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Error instantiating snitch class 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch'.
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:551) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:529) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createEndpointSnitch(DatabaseDescriptor.java:741) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:465) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:133) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:599) [apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:774) [apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Ec2Snitch was unable to execute the API call. Not an ec2 node?
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch.awsApiCall(Ec2Snitch.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
        at org.apache.cassandra.locator.Ec2Snitch.<init>(Ec2Snitch.java:55) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:536) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
```

Note: When I change snitch to SimpleSnitch it actually works.

Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question

Ec2snitch uses IMDVs1 to get metadata http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone to determine certain properties.

I created Ec2 instances through terraform where my code has

```
metadata_options {
  http_endpoint = "enabled"
    http_tokens = "enabled"
  }
```

The above code forces to use imdsv2 only which is causing the issue. Ec2snitch couldn't get metadata by simple curl command.

Solution:

```
metadata_options {
      http_endpoint = "enabled"
        http_tokens = "optional"
      }
```

If you are doing through console, when launching instance, make sure meta data version is set to V1 and V2

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this same error using `Ec2MultiRegionSnitch`, make sure that your instances have a public IP address attached to them.

Cassandra uses the http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4 to make a query when instantiating this snitch, if your instance doesn't use a public IP, this endpoint will return 404, and the startup will fail

This is the link to the constructor source code showing that behavior: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/48607b83952ab923c401fd7886d76a5a5a5b3c78/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/locator/Ec2MultiRegionSnitch.java#L46